# Fractal dimension of a trajectory

Tags: fractals, dimensional-analysis

In this paper, the author uses fractal dimension to measure the tortuosity of two-dimensional trajectory -
[Using Complexity Measures of Movement for Automatically Detecting Movement Types of Unknown GPS Trajectories](http://www.sapub.org/global/showpaperpdf.aspx?doi=10.5923/j.ajgis.20140302.01)

Here are some links about fractal dimension:
(1) [An introduction to fractals](http://davis.wpi.edu/~matt/courses/fractals/intro.html)
(2) [Fractal dimension](http://math.bu.edu/DYSYS/chaos-game/node6.html)

How do I calculate the fractal dimension of below trajectory?
[image]

Comment: I think the ideas in the paper are not likely to be applicable to a path with 6 steps. Rather, you need a process which (potentially) generates infinitely many steps.

Comment: If you have a *very* long path, it's not too hard to estimate the so-called [box-counting dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski%E2%80%93Bouligand_dimension) of the path. This is really just an estimate, though, to the fractal dimension that is expected to be generated by the process.

Comment: I've gone through the link but still not sure how the calculation goes.